# Execute create table inside stored procedure throws error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run this inside my stored procedure, but it's giving me error:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE "temp1"';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN      
            create table temp1(id number);            
        ELSE
      RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
```

I've also tried to put BEGIN END block around `create table temp1(id number)`, but error stays the same.

> Error:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the
> following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
> return select update while with       <<    continue close current
> delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute
> commit forall merge pipe purge
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:

Comment: As answered by @TenG, the CREATE must also be dynamic sql.  But in any event, this inclusion of DROP/CREATE TABLE in pl/sql block is almost always a bad idea.  This is usually the sort of thing for which oracle created Global Temporary Tables.

Comment: Is there anything I can use like some kind of temporary table or array of integers? Let's say, select into array of integers? I sql server it's so easy with temporary tables. @EdStevens - you are right about that. If I create global temporary table - it will stay there?

Comment: A Global Temporary Table is defined once and used many. Each connected session gets its own private 'version' of it. Data inserted into it remains until the session disconnects.  For more info, see the Concepts guide -- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88820

Comment: I've used GTT - I think it's great, because later I can also add as much columns as I want to. I don't like the fact that GTT is shown in tables, but OK. I am used to adhoc (table variables) tables from sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CREATE TABLE is also DDL just like the DROP so must also be run as dynamic SQL:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE "temp1"';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN      
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table temp1(id number)';            
        ELSE
      RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
```